# <script type="text/javascript"> failed to load Resourse for internal script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is the script tag with no src attribute is wrong?

I have written this script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('.select_subject').click(function(){
           jQuery('[name=subject_id]').val(jQuery(this).data('subject_id'));
           jQuery(this).parents('form').submit();
       });
   });       
</script>
```

I am getting this error on console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I am unable to understand what is the problem. I have included the jquery core library on header of page. Also there are some other javascripts codes that are included bfore this code but they did not throws any error. I have also attached a screenshot of the console.

[image]

**Update 1**

I tried after removing the type attribute. nothing happens :( .

I have included the jquery library version 1.9.1 in header.

[image]

**Update 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Bharat">
  <title>::Eduesy:: </title>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Bharat">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Bharat">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/css/student/web.css?1.0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/css/student/app.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/css/student/tooltip.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/css/student/custom.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/css/student/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/js/student/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.6.1/raven.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/js/student/vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/js/student/libs.all.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/js/student/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/js/student/tooltip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/js/student/tpr.web.min.js"></script>   
  <script src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/js/student/chartist.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if(jQuery(document).scrollTop()>0){
          jQuery(".header").addClass('header-fix');
        }else{
          jQuery(".header").removeClass('header-fix');
        }
      });   
      jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if(jQuery(document).scrollTop()>0){
          jQuery(".row-blue").addClass('header-fix');
        }else{
          jQuery(".row-blue").removeClass('header-fix');
        }
      });   
    }); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <header>    
        <div class="cf">    
            <div class="pTopHeader_dropdown pTopHeader_userDropdown non-selectable fr js-user-dropdown">
                <a class="pTopHeader_dropdown_trigger pTopHeader_userDropdown_trigger js-trigger">
                    <span class="profilename">Welcome Chandu</span> <img class="pTopHeader_userDropdown_thumb " alt="" src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/uploadedFiles/student/IMG_20150412_182136 (2) - Copy.jpg"/>
                </a>            
                <ul class="pTopHeader_dropdown_menu pTopHeader_dropdown_menu-right pTopHeader_userDropdown_menu js-dropdown">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/settings/profile.php" class="-strk"><span class="fa fa-tachometer pTopHeader_dropdown_menu_icon"></span>Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="-strk switch_class" rel="popuprel_course"><span class="fa fa-tachometer pTopHeader_dropdown_menu_icon"></span>Switch Course</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>                
                        <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/logout.php" class="-ref -strk"><span class="fa fa-power-off pTopHeader_dropdown_menu_icon"></span>Logout</a>                
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="pTopHeader_contactUpWrapper_trigger ph-16 fr phn-hide">            
                <a role="button" tabindex="0" class="pTopHeader_btn pTopHeader_appBtn button button-small button-white">Contact Us</a>
                <div class="pTopHeader_contactUpWrapper_tooltip">
                    <div class="contactTooltip">
                        <div class="cf">
                            <div class="contactTooltip_item">
                                <div class="contactTooltip_itemIcon contactTooltip_itemIcon-feedback"></div>
                                <div class="contactTooltip_title">Share Feedback</div>
                                <div class="contactTooltip_subtitle">Share your feedback for us. We are continuously working to improve your experience.</div>
                                <div class="contactTooltip_callUsNo"><a href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">abc@xyz.com</a></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="contactTooltip_item">
                                <div class="contactTooltip_itemIcon contactTooltip_itemIcon-callus"></div>
                                <div class="contactTooltip_title">Call us</div>
                                <div class="contactTooltip_subtitle">We are happy to hear from you. We are available from 9am to 6pm on all days.</div>
                                <div class="contactTooltip_callUsNo">+91 - 1800 123 456</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contactTooltip_footer">
                            <span class="contactTooltip_footer_mapIcon fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <div class="contactTooltip_footer_content">
                                <div class="contactTooltip_footer_title">Eduesy Online Education </div>
                                <div class="contactTooltip_footer_text">Mumbai - 400076, India</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                          
            <div class="pTopHeader_contactUpWrapper_trigger ph-16 fr phn-hide notification">            
                <a class="pTopHeader_btn pTopHeader_appBtn button button-small button-white"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>0</span></a>
            </div>         
            <div class="pTopHeader_contactUpWrapper_trigger ph-16 fr phn-hide btn-buy">            
                <a class="pTopHeader_btn pTopHeader_appBtn button button-small button-white">Buy</a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/lectures/index.php" class="mainSidebar_logoBlock_logo -ajaxify" title="EduEsy" style="width: 176px !important">
            <div class="mainSidebar_logoBlock_logo_img" style="background-image: url(http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/images/logo.png)"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mobileMenu">    
        <div class="mobileMenu_fallbackHeader"></div>    
        <div class="mobileMenu_hamburger js-hamburger-menu">   
            <div class="mobileMenu_hamburger_icon">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-blue">
    <div class="pull-left">
        Admission Taken Date: 29/05/2017
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        Student ID: EDUESY116 <span>|</span> Package Valid till: 25/12/2017
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.class_slider').click(function(){

            jQuery('[name=product_id]').val(jQuery(this).data('product_id'));
            jQuery('[name=product_type]').val(jQuery(this).data('product_type'));
            jQuery(this).parents('form').submit();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="popupbox" id="popuprel_course">

    <div id="intabdiv">
        <div id="test_tool_modals_wrapper">
            <div class="md mdTestPause js-test-pause-modal is-visible" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="close">X</div>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="obrdV2_container js-modules-container pb-10 ">
                        <div class="clr"></div>

                        <div class="obrdV2_module js-module-class js-module profiletype" data-module="profiletype">
                            <div class="p-20 clickable js-toggle-module">
                                <div class="obrdV2_module_image obrdV2_module_image-klass fl"></div>
                                <div class="obrdV2_module_heading js-module-heading">
                                    <div class="title">Choose one of the following</div>
                                    <div class="selectedValue js-selected-value"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="arrowDown js-arrow-down class" style="display: none;"></div>
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="obrdV2_module_body js-module-body visible ">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="item academic"><label><input type="radio" name="profileType" value="academic" id="academic" style="display: none;"> Academic</label></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="item professional"><label><input type="radio" name="profileType" value="professional" id="professional" style="display: none;">Professional Courses</label></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clr"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>

                        <div class="obrdV2_module js-module-class js-module address hide" data-module="address"></div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>


                        <div class="submit-row hide">
                            <div class="obrdV2_module js-module-class js-module submit" data-module="submit">
                                <div class="obrdV2_module_body js-module-body visible">
                                    <input type="submit" name="switchCourseSubmit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save and Continue">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mcustomscrollbar/3.0.6/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.actual/1.0.19/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.switch_class').click(function() {
            var popupid = $(this).attr('rel');
            $('#' + popupid).fadeIn();
            $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
            $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn();
            var popuptopmargin = ($('#' + popupid).height() + 10) / 2;
            var popupleftmargin = ($('#' + popupid).width() + 10) / 2;
            $('#' + popupid).css({
                'margin-top' : -popuptopmargin,
                'margin-left' : -popupleftmargin
            });
        });

        jQuery('body').on('click', '.popupbox .close', function() {
            jQuery(this).parents('.popupbox').fadeOut();
            jQuery('#fade').fadeOut();
            return false;
        });

        jQuery('.profiletype .js-module-body .item').on('click', function(evt){
            if (evt.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
                var profile = jQuery('[name="profileType"]:checked').val();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url         : 'http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/ajax_complete_profile.php',
                    type        : 'post',
                    data        : {action: 'profiletype', profiletype: profile},
                    beforeSend  : function(){
                        /*do nothing*/
                    },
                    success     : function(html){
                        jQuery('.level2').remove();
                        jQuery('.address').before(html);
                    }
                });

                jQuery(".address").addClass('hide');
                jQuery('.submit-row').addClass('hide');
            }
        });

        jQuery('.obrdV2_container').on('click', '.classtype', function(evt){
            if (evt.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
                var profile = jQuery('[name="classtype"]:checked').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url         : 'http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/ajax_complete_profile.php',
                    type        : 'post',
                    data        : {action: 'boardtype', profiletype: profile},
                    beforeSend  : function(){
                        /*do nothing*/
                    },
                    success     : function(html){
                        jQuery('.level3').remove();

                        jQuery('.address').before(html);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        jQuery('.obrdV2_container').on('click', '.boardListing', function(evt){
            if (evt.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
                var board = jQuery('[name="boardID"]:checked').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url         : 'http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/ajax_complete_profile.php',
                    type        : 'post',
                    data        : {action: 'classList', classList: board},
                    beforeSend  : function(){
                        /*do nothing*/
                    },
                    success     : function(html){
                        jQuery('.level4').remove();
                        jQuery('.address').before(html);
                    }
                });
                jQuery(".address").addClass('hide');
                jQuery('.submit-row').addClass('hide');
            }
        });

        jQuery('.obrdV2_container').on('click', '.obrdV2_klass', function(evt){
            if (evt.target.tagName == 'INPUT'){
                jQuery(this).siblings( '.selected').removeClass('selected');
                jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
                jQuery('.address').removeClass('hide'); 
                jQuery('.submit-row').removeClass('hide');
            }
        });

        jQuery('.obrdV2_container .address').on('change', function(evt){
            jQuery('.submit-row').removeClass('hide');
        });

        (function($){
            $(window).on("load",function(){
            var modal_ht = jQuery('#popuprel_course .popupbox').actual('height');
            jQuery("#popuprel_course #intabdiv").height(modal_ht);

            jQuery("#popuprel_course #intabdiv").mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollButtons:{enable:true},
                theme:"light-thick",
                scrollbarPosition:"outside",
                updateOnBrowserResize: true,
                updateOnContentResize: true
            });
        });
        })(jQuery);

    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .popupbox .close {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 8px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        z-index: 9999999999999999;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
  <div class="pageContentContainer">


 <div id="page_content_wrapper" class="js-page-content-wrapper">

   <div class="pHeader js-page-content">
<div class="cf">    
    <div class="pTopHeader_contactUpWrapper_trigger ph-16 fr phn-hide paging">
        <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student" >Dashboard</a> &raquo; <a href="index.php" >Lecture</a>
      &raquo; <a href="javascript:void(0);" >HTML JavaScript</a>
    </div></div>
   <div class="pHeader_content pt-25 pb-20 phn-pb-5 clearfix">
      <div class="container">
         <h1 class="h1 color-white normal">                    
            Lectures
         </h1>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pHeader_tabsWrapper js-page-tabs-wrapper">
      <div class="container">
         <nav role="navigation">
            <ul class="pHeader_tabs">
                  <li class=""><a data-tab="challenges_home" href="index.php?subject=51" class="-ajaxify -strk" >HTML Basic</a></li>   <li class=""><a data-tab="challenges_home" href="index.php?subject=52" class="-ajaxify -strk" >HTML Styles</a></li>   <li class="active"><a data-tab="challenges_home" href="index.php?subject=53" class="-ajaxify -strk" >HTML JavaScript</a></li>   <li class=""><a data-tab="challenges_home" href="index.php?subject=54" class="-ajaxify -strk" >HTML And XHTML</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pHeader_tabsSpacing"></div>
</div>
<div class="container js-page-content">
   <div class="coachmarks_icon coachmarks_icon_selectSubject hide js-coachmarks"></div>
</div>
<div class="container pv-30 cf">
   <div class="pCol pCol-wide alpha js-pageLearn">
      <aside class="pCol pCol-narrow omega phn-mt-40">
         <div class="heading heading-bordered h3 bold">Chapters</div>
         <div class="cf mt-30 mb-50">
            <a href="topic.php?topic=26"><div class="chapterTile tile tile-shadowed select_subject cf js-chapter-tile  mb-20 tab-mb-20 phn-mb-15" data-subject_id="19">

            <div class="chapterTile_arrowContainer">
                <h2 class="chapterTile_title ">HTML File Paths</h2>
                <span class="tile_arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            </div></div></a>
         </div>
      </aside>
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar-common">
    <h2>Our mission is to provide a world class education to anyone, anywhere.</h2>
    <h3>You will receive inside.</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><label><img src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/images/student/img-video.png" /></label>Video Lecture</li>
        <li><label><img src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/images/student/img-test-series.png" /></label>Test Series</li>
        <li><label><img src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/images/student/img-study-material.png" /></label>Study Material</li>
        <li><label><img src="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/images/student/img-doubt-section.png" /></label>Doubt Section</li>
    </ul>
</div>

   <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('.select_subject').click(function(){
           jQuery('[name=subject_id]').val(jQuery(this).data('subject_id'));
           jQuery(this).parents('form').submit();
       });
   });

</script>

</div>

<div class="container">
   <footer class="footer mv-20">
      <ul>
         <li>&copy; Eduesy</li>
         <span class="footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/page.php?id=2" target="_blank">About</a></li>
         <span class="footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="/upgrade/">Upgrade</a></li>
         <span class="footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="/contact-us/" class="-ajaxify">Contact</a></li>
         <span class="footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="/terms/" target="_blank">Terms</a></li>
         <span class="footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="/bytes/" target="_blank">Bytes</a></li>
         <span class="footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="https://blog.toppr.com/" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clr"></div>
   </footer>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="mainSidebar js-main-sidebar">    
   <div class="mainSidebar_switcherBlock js-class-switcher">
      <a class="mainSidebar_switcherBlock_switch js-selected-class"> HTML</a>
      <div class="mainSidebar_switcherBlock_dropdown js-dropdown">
         <form method="post" action="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/lectures/index.php">
           <label class="mainSidebar_switcherBlock_option class_slider js-switchOption selected" data-class-title="HTML " data-product_id="47" data-product_type="Course" selected>HTML<div class="mainSidebar_switcherBlock_option_tickMark fa fa-check"></div></label><label class="mainSidebar_switcherBlock_option class_slider js-switchOption " data-class-title="Advance PHP " data-product_id="61" data-product_type="Course" >Advance PHP<div class="mainSidebar_switcherBlock_option_tickMark fa fa-check"></div></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="course" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_type" value="47" />
            <input type="hidden" name="change_product_type" value="1" />
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
   <nav role="navigation" class="mainSidebar_contentBlock mainSidebar_contentBlock-withSwitcher js-main-sidebar-content-block">
      <div class="mainSidebar_sHeading">Study Modules</div>
      <ul class="mainSidebar_sNav js-mainSidebar-study">
         <li data-tab="learn" class="active open">
            <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/lectures/index.php" class="-ajaxify q_tip_w" original-title="Lectures">
               <div class="iconWrapper">
                  <i class="fa fa-file-video-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </div>
               <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
               <div class="label">Lectures</div>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li data-tab="practice" class="">
            <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/practice/index.php" class="-ajaxify q_tip_w" original-title="Practice">
               <div class="iconWrapper">
                  <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </div>
               <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
               <div class="label">Practice</div>
            </a>
         </li>

         <li data-tab="tests" class="">
            <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/tests/index.php" class="js-lhs-ts-link q_tip_w -ajaxify -strk">
               <div class="iconWrapper">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </div>
               <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
               <div class="label">Tests</div>
            </a>
         </li> 

         <li data-tab="tests" class=""><a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/exam/index.php" class="js-lhs-ts-link q_tip_w"><div class="iconWrapper"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span><div class="label">Exam</div></a></li>

         <li data-tab="doubts" class="">
            <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/doubt/index.php"
            class="-strk -ajaxify q_tip_w js-startDoc">
            <div class="iconWrapper">
               <i class="fa fa-weixin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            <div class="label">Doubts</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li data-tab="challenges" class="">
         <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/challenges/index.php" class="-ajaxify q_tip_w">
            <div class="iconWrapper">
               <i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            <div class="label">Challenges</div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="mainSidebar_sHeading">My Profile</div>
   <ul class="mainSidebar_sNav js-mainSidebar-compare">
      <li data-tab="dashboard" class="">
         <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/dashboard/index.php" class="-ajaxify q_tip_w" original-title="Dashboard">
            <div class="iconWrapper">
               <i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            <div class="label">Dashboard</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li data-tab="my_bookmarks" class="">
         <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/placement/index.php" class="-ajaxify -bookmarks q_tip_w">
            <div class="iconWrapper">
               <i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            <div class="label">Placement</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li data-tab="achievements" class="">
         <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/achievement/index.php" class="-ajaxify q_tip_w">
            <div class="iconWrapper">
               <i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            <div class="label">Achievements</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li data-tab="leaderboard" class="">
         <a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/student/leaderboard/index.php" class="-ajaxify -strk q_tip_w">
            <div class="iconWrapper">
               <i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="arrow fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            <div class="label">Leaderboard</div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="mainSidebar_sHeading">Study Tools</div>
   <footer class="mainSidebar_footer mv-20">
      <ul class="cf">
         <li>&copy; Eduesy</li>
         <span class="mainSidebar_footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="#" target="_blank">About</a></li>
         <span class="mainSidebar_footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li>
         <a href="#" target="_blank">Discuss</a>
         </li>
         <span class="mainSidebar_footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/blog/" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
         <span class="mainSidebar_footer_dot">&#8226;</span>
         <li><a href="http://eduesy.fsas.co.in/page.php?id=14" target="_blank">Terms</a></li>
      </ul>
   </footer>
</nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `type=text/javascript` can safely be removed. It has not been needed for several years. **Also, make sure that your other scripts on the page are properly closed.**

Comment: **^^Agree with the above^^** And be sure to include the `jQuery` Library before your script.

Comment: @NewToJS OP says that JQuery is included. Even if it weren't, it wouldn't produce a 404 error, it would produce `jQuery is undefined`.

Comment: @sc Did not resolved

Comment: @ScottMarcus I know hence agreeing with your comment but I thought it might be relevant to point out a double check on including the required library as it appears to be a common mistake which then leads into further problems as you have pointed out... normally `$` is `undefined` Also the screenshot is inspect element not the console which logs those errors.

Comment: crossed checked again and there is no error like `$ is undefined`

Comment: Please, instead of showing pictures of your code, just include the actual code in your question. Additionally, while you are seeing the error being reported on line 587, this error is most likely being caused by an improper `script` that occurs earlier in the document, so please show all the relevant code. Lastly, if you click over to your `Network` tab in the developer's tools, you should be able to see more details on what resource the 404 is emanating from.

Comment: You are not going to see `$ is undefined` because you are not referring to JQuery as `$`, you are using `jQuery`. And, as  I stated, that's the error you would see if you had not included JQuery, which you told us you were, so we don't have to be looking for this kind of error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have shared all source code.

Comment: Ok, upon looking your code over, I can tell you that you have *many* problems. First, you do have JQuery referenced, but not before **all** of your scripts that use it and you are actually getting both `$ is undefined` and `jQuery is undefined` because you are using both `$` and `jQuery` to reference the JQuery object. If you are not using another library that uses `$`, then just use `$` and not `jQuery`. Next, you have a `window.onload` function nested inside of a JQuery `document.ready` event handler, which is redundant and confusing. Also, your HTML is not even valid....

Comment: ...Run it through the [W3C Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org) and correct all your errors. And, while you are doing that, you can remove all your `type=` attributes on both your `script` tags and your `style` tags.

Answer (score 0):

ShowMsg('Access denied ! ! !'); Access denied ! ! !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).